# Images not showing on website when accessed by IP Address

Tags: .net, iis, web, iis-8.5

I have an internal web site hosted on a Windows server (2012 R2). When I access the site by the name "vhac" I can see all images on a certain page.  However, if I go to the same page in the site using the IP address (10.10.10.10) one of the images doesn't show up.

The site is under the Default Web Site in IIS. The image is in a directory on the server that is mapped as a virtual directory for the default web site. The only binding that is setup is http, no host name, port 80, All unassigned IP addresses, which I believe is just the default.

The URL of the image is \\10.10.10.10\MIL\image.jpg

Edit: this is all on IE11

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Images not showing on website when accessed by IP Address:

```
1.) Check User Access credentials.
2.) Check user permission Folder Properties=>security.
3.) Check user account accessed to mapped image server.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Would my user change based on the URL I'm accessing the website from?  I'm logging into the website as the same admin user. I don't get why http://vhac vs http://ipaddress behaves differently when they point to the same site.

Comment: sometimes images working in localhost but not working in IIS because of image path. But sometimes because of user permission too to image folder.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug this, since you're using IE. Is go into the Developer Tools (F12) --> Go to the network tab --> Press the green start arrow (if it's not started) then reload the page and see what errors are being tossed for the images.

Once you know what the HTTP error codes are, it will be much easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

So figured out that using the IP Address in the URL is treated as an Internet site in IE, while the named loads as intranet. From there saw that there were different security settings. I added the IP address to the trusted sites and now everything works. Hope this dumb mistake helps somebody else out.